# csshX not working in Ventura

Tags: terminal, third-party, perl, ventura

I upgraded to Ventura this weekend, and now `csshX` won't run. I get the error messages

```
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam(): use File::Temp instead at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/POSIX.pm line 185.
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam() at /Users/barmar/bin/csshX line 1130.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/barmar/bin/csshX line 1130.
```

I don't think the solutions at [csshX not working on Mac OS Big Sur](https://superuser.com/questions/1602045/csshx-not-working-on-mac-os-big-sur) will work because `perl5.18` doesn't exist any more. The only versions of perl are 5.30 and 5.34.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/brockgr/csshx/issues/103). I made a private copy of `csshX` and changed

```
use POSIX qw(tmpnam);
```

to

```
use File::Temp qw/ :POSIX /;
```

Comment: This did not fix it for me on Ventura 13.2.1, but instead I needed to follow a few additional steps: 1: leave usee POSIX qw(tmpname) where it  is, add the additional line. PLUS: Do what is mentioned here at line 1131.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that csshX seems to choke on modern versions of Bash. After downloading [a forked version](https://github.com/pwalz/csshx) containing the fixes needed to get it running, I still got an error:

```
No master at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1300.
 at (eval 11) line 1.
    main::__ANON__("No master at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1300.\x{a}") called at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1300
    CsshX::Launcher::new("CsshX::Launcher") called at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 2306
```

I found [an old complaint](https://github.com/brockgr/csshx/issues/47#issuecomment-77056031) about a similar issue that was resolved by changing the shell. I had the Terminal.app setting "Shells open with" set to `/opt/local/bin/bash`. Instead I set the Terminal setting back to "Default login shell"

[image: screenshot showing the specified setting]

Then I updated my login shell:

```sh
sudo echo '/opt/local/bin/bash' >> /etc/shells
chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash
```

Now, new windows still open with my preferred shell, but the csshX master window uses the system default and seems to work well. Impressive for a 12 year old piece of software!

Comment: Since MacOS is still stuck on an ancient version of `bash` (unless you upgrade it yourself), this is not likely to be an issue for most users.

Comment: I'm running a version from MacPorts. Agree it won't be a problem for most, but I don't think it's such an edge case that it's not worth mentioning.